# Как получить все возможные варианты удаления элементов из отсортированного списка?

Tags: java

Например есть отсортированный список: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
Каким образом можно получить возможные варианты с удалением элементов?
Чтобы вначале удалялся один элемент, потом два, потом три и т.д.
Как я понимаю необходимо использовать рекурсию.
В результате должно получиться

```
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 4]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
```

Comment: Порядок важен? Или достаточно перечислить все подмножества в произвольном порядке?

Comment: Задание выглядит как учебное. Пожалуйста, добавьте код вашей попытки решить задачу.

Answer (score 0):

По сути каждый элемент может участвовать или не участвовать в результате.

Отсюда можно придумать алгоритм. Я на C# его напишу, на Java там 1-1 почти будет.

```
public void AllCases(int[] data, int ind, List<int> current, List<List<int>> ret)
{
    if (ind >= data.Length)
    {
        ret.Add(new List<int>(current));
        return;
    }

    current.Add(data[ind]);
    AllCases(data, ind + 1, current, ret); // участвует

    current.RemoveAt(current.Count - 1);
    AllCases(data, ind + 1, current, ret); // не участвует
}
```

Проверка элементарная

```
var ret = new List<List<int>>();
AllCases(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 0, new List<int>(), ret);

foreach (var list in ret)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
```

Вывод

```
1, 2, 3, 4
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 4
1, 2
1, 3, 4
1, 3
1, 4
1
2, 3, 4
2, 3
2, 4
2
3, 4
3
4
```